# Is it possible to publish two messages to rabbitMQ atomically?

Tags: transactions, rabbitmq, amqp

It is a common enough use case that when some given fact occurs on a backend service that an event is published. But let's say that I want to publish two or more different events in response to this fact which occurred, is it possible to have all-or-nothing guarantees (either all messages are published to the exchange or none are) with rabbitMQ?

The AMQP spec defines a tx class with transactional semantics and the rabbitMQ documentation has a [page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html) on it which is rather confusing. It states:

> AMQP guarantees atomicity only when transactions involve a single queue, i.e. all the publishes inside the tx get routed to a single queue ... Furthermore, RabbitMQ provides no atomicity guarantees even in case of transactions involving just a single queue, e.g. a fault during tx.commit can result in a sub-set of the transaction's publishes appearing in the queue after a broker restart.

What is the truth behind it all, is it possible to have all-or-nothing semantics when publishing two or more messages to rabbitMQ (to the same exchange, but possibly being routed to different queues) ? And if not is there a way to achieve the same effect ?

Comment: Has differences between messages?

Comment: @LuizCarlosFaria The payloads are the same, but semantically they are different messages. They represent different events which happened to the same entity, and although they may be published to the same exchange they are definitely gonna be routed to different queues.